# Check if cell content contains specific shape

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a table that contains some text with upper line, the upper line changes the meaning of the text, I want to be able to determine for each cell if it contains a line shape or not.

From what I saw, there's a cell.part.inline_shapes but it gives the same results for each cell in the table, and it the doesn't specify the actual shape (line/rectangular/square etc.).

e.g. in the following table, only cell [1, 0] is containing line

[image: Example table]

```py
def is_line(shape):
    #TODO implement
    pass

def is_containing_line(cell):
    # TODO: check if shape is in current cell, as cell.part.inline_shapes are the same in every table cell    
    cell_shapes = cell.part.inline_shapes
    return any(is_line(shape) for shape in cell_shapes)


[i for i, cell in enumerate(table.columns[column_index].cells[starting_row:])
if is_containing_line(cell)]
```

print(cell._tc.xml) for cell that contains line shape:

```html
<w:tc xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
  xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml"
  xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
  <w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="1734" w:type="dxa" />
    <w:tcBorders>
      <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="12" w:space="0" w:color="000000" />
      <w:bottom w:val="nil" />
    </w:tcBorders>
  </w:tcPr>
  <w:p>
    <w:pPr>
      <w:pStyle w:val="TableParagraph" />
      <w:spacing w:before="10" />
      <w:rPr>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="2" />
      </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
  </w:p>
  <w:p>
    <w:pPr>
      <w:pStyle w:val="TableParagraph" />
      <w:spacing w:line="20" w:lineRule="exact" w:before="0" />
      <w:ind w:left="755" />
      <w:rPr>
        <w:sz w:val="2" />
      </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:sz w:val="2" />
      </w:rPr>
      <w:pict>
        <v:group style="width:11.1pt;height:.6pt;mso-position-horizontal-relative:char;mso-position-vertical-relative:line" coordorigin="0,0" coordsize="222,12">
          <v:rect style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:222;height:12" filled="true" fillcolor="#000000" stroked="false">
            <v:fill type="solid" />
          </v:rect>
        </v:group>
      </w:pict>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:sz w:val="2" />
      </w:rPr>
    </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:p>
    <w:pPr>
      <w:pStyle w:val="TableParagraph" />
      <w:spacing w:before="0" />
      <w:ind w:left="453" w:right="449" />
      <w:jc w:val="center" />
      <w:rPr>
        <w:sz w:val="16" />
      </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:sz w:val="16" />
      </w:rPr>
      <w:t>EN</w:t>
    </w:r>
  </w:p>
</w:tc>
```

print(cell._tc.xml) for cell that doesn't contain line shape:

```html
<w:tc xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
  xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml"
  xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
  <w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="1734" w:type="dxa" />
  </w:tcPr>
  <w:p>
    <w:pPr>
      <w:pStyle w:val="TableParagraph" />
      <w:spacing w:before="55" />
      <w:ind w:left="453" w:right="448" />
      <w:jc w:val="center" />
      <w:rPr>
        <w:sz w:val="16" />
      </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:sz w:val="16" />
      </w:rPr>
      <w:t>BOUT</w:t>
    </w:r>
  </w:p>
</w:tc>
```

Comment: You need to add simplified version of your code and the table you're working on.

Comment: Is the line created using some ascii/unicode character? (such as U+0100 which is  Ā) or is is created some other way?

Comment: @HarmManders it's created using the shape feature in word docx ( Insert tab -> Shapes -> lines)

Comment: @Wahalez I've add them, but I really have nothing in the code since I don't know what I should be looking for, I think it's a matter of what fields I need to access in the Cell object, but I couldn't find anything helpful while debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API support for this in `python-docx`.

However, this function will tell you whether a drawing (inline-shape) is present in a paragraph. Note that depending on the Word version, such an item may appear as a `<w:pict>` (bitmap image) element instead of a `<w:drawing>` (vector art) element:

```
def has_inline_shape(paragraph):
    """Return True if `paragraph` contains an inline shape."""
    return (
        bool(paragraph._p.xpath(".//w:drawing"))
        or bool(paragraph._p.xpath(".//w:pict"))
    )
```

You can apply it to each paragraph in a cell to determine whether the cell contains such a shape:

```
def cell_contains_inline_shape(cell):
    """Return True if an inline-shape appears in `cell`."""
    return any(
        has_inline_shape(paragraph)
        for paragraph in cell.paragraphs
    )
```

Comment: It didn't work, it returns False for all the cells

Comment: If you access that particular cell and `print(cell._tc.xml)`, what do you get? Add that to your original question and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me:
`return bool(paragraph._p.xpath(".//w:drawing")) or bool(paragraph._p.xpath(".//w:pict"))`

Comment: Ah, good catch @efrat, I've elaborated my answer to include that possible `<w:pict>` fallback.